# Global variables changing whilst setTimeout() in operation

Tags: javascript

I've been looking for hours for a solution to this but with no luck.
1) The user clicks a button and an image file name is saved to a global variable.
2) The user clicks on another div on the page and first an animated image plays for 5 seconds.
3) After 5 seconds the animated image is replaced (at same 'src' location) by the image file reference saved to a global variable in stage 1.

This all works great as long as the user doesn't click a different image (thus changing the variable in stage 1) during those 5 seconds, if they do then the variable is updated before the second image is placed.

I've tried using bracket notation to send the contents of the variable to another function, because I thought this would make the variable 'pause' somehow unique, but that doesn't work. I've also split the functions up but that doesn't help.
I've never used an array before but I also tried pushing each selection into the back of an array and pulling out the first item when required, but this was a little beyond me. Can anyone suggest the best way to store each variable uniquely for those 5 seconds?

```
  function makeSelection(iGCode) {
    var itemGroupVar = $(event.target).attr('id');
    /*var itemGroupGet = document.getElementById(itemGroup);*/
    var groupIDBColor = document.getElementById(itemGroupVar).style.backgroundColor;
    selectedItemCache = iGCode;
    if (groupIDBColor == '') {
      resetHighlighted();
      document.getElementById(itemGroupVar).style.backgroundColor = 'rgba(255, 0, 0)';
    } else {
      document.getElementById(itemGroupVar).style.backgroundColor = '';
      selectedItemCache = '';
    }
  } 


  function populateCell(clicked_id)
  {
      var clicked_id2 = "i"+clicked_id;
      document.getElementById(clicked_id2).src = 'images/constructionAnim/constructionAnim1.svg';
      pauseBuild([clicked_id2]);
  }
  function pauseBuild(pause)
  {
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
      document.getElementById(pause).src = selectedItemCache;
    }, 4000);
  }
```

```
<div class="itemGroup itemsRes" id="group1" onclick="makeSelection('images/h100-500-1f-01.svg')">

<div class="r1d allCells" id="c0001" onClick="populateCell(this.id)"><img id="ic0001" src=""></div>
<div class="r1d allCells" id="c0002" onClick="populateCell(this.id)"><img id="ic0002" src=""></div>
```

Comment: From your code it looks like the `pause` variable will always be unique.  It is passed into the `pauseBuild` method and is a string.  So that is not mutable.  Your `selectedItemCache`, however, is a global variable that is subject to being changed before the setTimeout executes.

Comment: Before solving this problem you need to define what you *want* to happen when the user does this. If the user clicks another image before the timer expires, should it add to a queue and replace it after the current one? Should it ignore it completely? Restart the timer with the newly clicked image? This decision informs how you can alter your logic to account for this.

Comment: Global variables should be avoided for this exact reason.

Comment: Hi Klaycon. The user may very well click a differnt div. So I want each second selection to be independent, but I want the image chosen to place to be stored until another image is chosen. I would however like the user to be able to select the image they want to use (stage 1) and then place that image in multiple divs one after the other, hence the

Answer (score 0):

Taplar nailed it. I needed to make both variable names unique with []. I hadn't realised this as the contents of only one was unique but of course it was the variable name which was causing an issue. Thanks all for your help.

```
  function populateCell(clicked_id)
  {
      var clicked_id2 = "i"+clicked_id;
      document.getElementById(clicked_id2).src = 'images/constructionAnim/constructionAnim1.svg';
      var selectedItemCache2 = selectedItemCache;
      pauseBuild([clicked_id2],[selectedItemCache2]);
  }
  function pauseBuild(pause,pause2)
  {
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
      document.getElementById(pause).src = pause2;
    }, 4000);
  }
```